# is it possible to share a VM snapshot image from GCP to AWS and vice-versa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I want to load an Snapshot image from Google cloud platform to AWS. Can someone tell me brief steps if this is possible ? Are there any best practices around it ?

Comment: For data disks this is easy, look at @mahboob's answer. For the boot (root) disk, this is not so simple. Google installs a lot of stuff on their systems and so does AWS. Think thru how you will switch over the services that are cloud vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Cloud Endure](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MQCH96B?qid=1588779673674&sr=0-3&ref_=srh_res_product_title).

It should be able to copy an outside VM onto an EC2 Host and create the AMI for you

Answer (score 0):

As per the GCP document [enter here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console) you can transfer data from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) to AWS. Before that, you need to export the snapshot/image to the GCS bucket. To export the image, please use the below mentioned gcloud command.

‘gcloud alpha compute images export --destination-uri gs://[BUCKET]/image.vmdk --image [IMAGE-NAME] --export-format vmdk --project [PROJECT-ID]’

Please note that, create an image from the snapshot then transfer it to the GCS bucket.

Comment: As per the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer#setting_up_an_amazon_s3_data_transfer) you can transfer data to/from AWS